# How to configure phpMD plugin in NetBeans 6.9 (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, netbeans

I've written a custom XML ruleset, so I run phpmd with the following command:

```
phpmd /path/to/my/file.module xml ruleset.xml
```

Now I've downloaded and installed the phpmd/CodeSniffer plugin for netbeans (http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmdnb/files/), but I can't find the way to configure it properly.

Going to Tools -> Options -> PHP, I find the phpMD tab, in which I can change settings.

No idea what to put in each field.

If I put the binary in the field "phpMD batch file:", netbeans throws the error "The file /usr/bin/phpmd isn't the right phpMD batch".

Has anyone successfully installed this interesting plugin?

Comment: I have not tried this plugin as I use NetBeans 7.0, but there is a CodeSniffer plugin that works. I followed the [instructions](http://www.amaxus.com/cms-blog/coding-standards-netbeans-php-codesniffer), and I had to activate the plugin after installing it to see the options panel. Works great!

Answer (score 2):

you must place your ruleset file into the default phpmd folder "rulesets" which is normaly located at **$PEAR/data/PHP_PMD/rulesets/**.
Now you can simply set the ruleset name in NetBeans PHP-MD Plugin configuration.
As batch file you must choose phpmd from your php binary folder.

If you still get any errors, please submit a bug report on the plugin page http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmdnb/

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

Carles,

I haven't played with this particular plugin. However, approach I've used for workarounding other plugins' issues could help here as well.

So the approach is to create a wrapper script. That could be bash, for example, on Linix/Mac or bar on Windows. Use this wrapper in plugin settings as main executable.
With this approach you can gain full flexibility - you can pass whatever parameters you want and so on. NetBeans may (and most likely will) pass some parameters to that script (depending on plugin). That is quite easy to debug. 
Here is an example of such wrapper in bash, written for PHPUnit:

```
#!/bin/bash
#

localInputFile=${7:4}
localJUnitLog=$2
localCoverageLog=$4
remoteInputFile=`echo $localInputFile | sed "s|$localPath|$remotePath|g"`

remoteJUnitLog=${remotePath}nb-phpunit-log.xml
remoteJUnitLoginLocalFilePath=${localPath}nb-phpunit-log.xml
remoteCoverageLog=${remotePath}nb-phpunit-coverageClover.xml
remoteCoverageLoginLocalFilePath=${localPath}nb-phpunit-coverageClover.xml
remoteCoverageLoginLocalFilePathNew=${remoteCoverageLoginLocalFilePath}new

ssh root@<remote-server> "phpunit --colors --log-junit $remoteJUnitLog --coverage-clover $remoteCoverageLog $remoteInputFile"
cp $remoteJUnitLoginLocalFilePath $localJUnitLog
sed "s|$remotePath|$localPath|g" $remoteCoverageLoginLocalFilePath > $remoteCoverageLoginLocalFilePathNew
cp $remoteCoverageLoginLocalFilePathNew $localCoverageLog
```

This one I've used to force PHPUnit NetBeans plugin to use phpunit not at localhost, but at the remote server. But what you need here is the way parameters are caught. You could debug that doing just

```
echo $0 $1 $2
```

and opening output window in Netbeans to see the result.

Hope this would help.